# Problems with Slony, pgAdmin and cluster replication

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, slony

I'm having some problems with replication in pgAdmin. It says:

> Slony creation scripts not available.

I use `File > Options` and indicate the path "usr/share/slony" where I suppose they are. Because that directory has `xxid.v80.sql` and all of them.

My problem is, pgAdmin still doesn't recognize the creation scripts for the cluster.

My setup: SO-Ubuntu, pgAdmin, PostgreSQL 8.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason version 1.2 of slony has some troubles with pgadmin3 1.10 or postgres 8.4 (That's what I asume). I just uninstalled version of slony from sinaptyc and installed slony v2.0.6 from source (slony1.tar.bz2) and everything worked fine for postgres 8.4

Hope this helps,